# How are you supposed to interactively debug Swift classes in XCode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

With Obj-C there's never any problem viewing values interactively within XCode, with Swift however how is this supposed to be done. Here's an example, I want to see what the values of a view controller's frame is, here the code and the current line of execution:

[image]

And here's what the variables window show fully expanded:

[image]

That is totally useless for viewing inherited values.

Ok lets try po.

[image]

[image]

Is this a joke? Why is po saying vc is unresolved when clearly it must be in scope at the breakpoint.

So how is one supposed to view variables interactively in Swift in XCode?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a bug with Xcode / lldb, as what you're trying to print should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to what are you mentioning:

> I want to see what the values of a view controller's frame is

UIViewController *does not* has a frame, you probably meant to see its [view](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621460-view) frame.

However, the easiest way -for me- to see such values, is to add an expression, as follows:

After reaching the desired breakpoint:

- In the debug area - variables view, right clicking and choosing "Add Expression..." option should display the following pop-up view:

[image]

- You can add -as an expression- whatever object you want to trace, i.e to see its actual value. For instance, I added `self.view.frame` and the output was (iphone 6 simulator):

[image]

For your specific case, adding `vc.view.frame` -as an expression- should display what are you looking for.

Hope this helped.