# Why am I unable to view values in debug area?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, xcode8

After adding an expression -in the debug area-:

[image]

I am facing an issue, which is: when reaching the desired line (via a breakpoint), the value is always appears as "Invalid expression", with a message logged to the console:

> Shared Swift state for (My Project Name) has developed fatal errors
>   and is being discarded.
>
> REPL definitions and persistent names/types will be lost.

To double check that the variable has a value (also as a workaround to see what is the actual value of the variable), I tried to log it via `dump()` and it seems that it *does* has a value.

Although there is a workaround -as I mentioned, by using `dump()`-, I wonder what is the reason of causing this issue?

I am not pretty sure if it could be a bug in the Xcode; I am using Xcode version 8.3.2.

---

*Remark:* If you have no idea what is adding an expression into the debug area, you might want to check [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214267/how-are-you-supposed-to-interactively-debug-swift-classes-in-xcode).

Comment: What is your expression?

Comment: because bugs. the IDE isnt always ok. you can sometimes do `po` as a workaround too

Comment: Hello @shallowThought, it is an array of custom objects (class that inherits from `NSObject`).

Comment: Can you show it to reproduce?